# Showing only 1 piece of data in php curl

Tags: php, json, curl, php-curl

MY JSON FILE get the json file

```
{
  "isSuccess": true,
  "data": {
    "usersType": 1,
    "users": [  
      {
        "uid": 1,
        "unumber": 2,
        "utel": 265954452,
        "un": "Cedric",
        "ul": "Williams",
        "ucid": 1,
        "uregdate": "2020-07-01T22:45:00",
        "ed": 15,
        "uregdates": "July Wednesday 1",
        "edh": "22:45",
        "en": "Admin",
        "mb": null,
        "admin": true,
        "mc": 0,
        "userticketid": 22419949 
      },
      {
        "uid": 2,
        "unumber": 2,
        "utel": 16595197,
        "un": "Michael",
        "ul": "Lovato",
        "ucid": 2,
        "uregdate": "2020-07-02T15:00:00",
        "ed": 159,
        "uregdates": "July Thursday 2",
        "edh": "15:00",
        "en": "User",
        "mb": null,
        "admin": false,
        "mc": 0,
        "userticketid": 52638722
      }
    ] 
    
  },
  "message": "",
  "error": null,
  "info": null,
  "date": null
}
```

MY PHP FILE use curl

```
$url = 'http://localhost/json';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$result_arr = json_decode($result);


foreach($result_arr->data->users as $ok)  
    {   
    
    $uid = $ok->uid;
    $un  = $ok->un;
    $en = $ok->en;
    $uregdates = $ok->uregdates;
    $uregdate = $ok->uregdate;
    $userticketid = $ok->userticketid;
    
    }
    
    echo $id." ".$un." ".$en." ".$uregdates." ".$uregdate." ".$userticketid;
```

Showing only 1 piece of data and I want "usersType": 1, > go show list "users": []

I want all echo all variable. Pls can u help me
Where's the problem? Can you help me find
I tried every way. Curl functions fail
Can you list it completely?
I will draw a lot of data

Comment: Hi Ercan, Welcome to SO, please tell clearly how you want the output to look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `echo` should be inside `foreach` loop. Here is how it should be

```
foreach($result_arr->data->users as $ok)  {   
    
    $uid = $ok->uid;
    $un  = $ok->un;
    $en = $ok->en;
    $uregdates = $ok->uregdates;
    $uregdate = $ok->uregdate;
    $userticketid = $ok->userticketid;
    
    echo $uid." ".$un." ".$en." ".$uregdates." ".$uregdate." ".$userticketid;
}
```